# Android DownloadManager Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, download, anchor, trust

I have searched through many posts but no where I could find any solution or the answer to my question.
How can I download files from my site where is intermediate cert installed? 
While using DownloadManager, I'm getting error " java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." when trying to download a file. I have seen posts that I should use something like in this post https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java
But I do not really know how should I set SslSocketFactory for the downloadmanager so he could use it to download files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found solution.
Just add to your manifest

and to res -> xml -> new file network_security_config with following lines of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.pl</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="@raw/path_to_cert"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```